# Git autocomplete on oh-my-zsh not finding branch names

Tags: macos, git, zsh, autocomplete

Somehow last week my git autocompletion on Oh-my-zsh, on my iterm app on mac started behaving strangely.

if I type `git checkout` and then  I used to get autocompletion on the branch names, so I was seeing autocompletion suggestions like:

```
master
development
feature/.....
```

I'm not sure what changed, but suddenly I started getting autocompletion on the commit numbers, if I type the same I get something like below:

```
2df4909
ea81288
eb57e90




31b1d73


-- Merge pull request #98
-- added new action
-- fixing test
391adf3
```

Where 391adf3 is a merge commit, with commit message `merge pull req #98`

I wonder what happened, what could I check out?

These are the plugins I have installed in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
plugins=(capistrano jira ruby rails gem rake-fast rvm textmate brew cap bundler dirhistory last-working-dir git git-extras)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `git-extras` from the list, it will solve your issue.

Comment: "Try removing" ... "seems to solve". Well does it solve it or not? It it doesn't it is not an answer. If it does please make that clear.

Comment: Noted on the above. Edited accordingly.